# How to know download manager is downloading a file from particular url?

Tags: android, url, download, android-download-manager

I am downloading a file using download manager in android studio and showing download progress in an activity too. For this, I use the downloadId I get when I enqueue the download request and then querying the download manager using the downloadId.

Now, how would I show the download progress again in my activity after the user exits the app and opens again??? I have bunch of downloads that is taking place.

What I am hoping for is something like this. Check whether download to a particular url exists in the download manager. If download to the url exists in download manager, I would just show the progress again by querying through the request.

Comment: `I am downloading a file` Ok. A file. `I have bunch of downloads that is taking place.`? Well that looks more than one suddenly.

Comment: yeah well, I thought the answer was gonna be store the downloadId in shared preferences and check for its progress again.  I do not want to do that. If I have a bunch of files downloading then its not feasible to store all the ids. As I asked, I want to know whether download manager is downloading from a particular url. Any help will be appreciated.